# Creating a custom desribe summary table for a number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
d = {'eue_scanner': [1,2,3,4,5],
     'eue_thinclient': [12,1221,2123,1231, 123],
     'service_model': ['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Bronze', 'Silver', 'Silver']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to create a describe table that will look like this (ignore actual numbers):

[image]

```
df['eue_thinclient'].describe().to_csv("my_description.csv")
```

but I would want all these summary tables in this formatting for the rest. Here is the code I have:

```
for smf, df_smf in df_final.groupby('service_model'):
    for col in columns_for_stats:
        print(smf,"-", col)
        print(df_smf[col].describe())
        df_smf[col].describe().to_csv("my_description.csv")
        break
    break
```

The `column_for_stats` list is just this:

```
column_for_stats = ['eue_scanner', 'eue_thinclient']
```

but for all the different combinations. Here is the expected csv output in picture form

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected csv output as text?

Comment: @mozway Sorry I do not understand, what do you mean as text?

Comment: @Wolfy, that means: post the expected structure of your `"my_description.csv"`, how all `service_model`s are supposed to be aligned (disregarding to the actual stat numbers)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Ideally, I would like it to be structured such that there are 4 tables per row seprated by some white space between the outer borders. I can post a sample picture if that would help?

Comment: @Wolfy What do you mean by "for all the different combinations"? Does your current code (commenting out the "break" lines) not account for "all different combinations"?

Comment: @Wolfy, *I can post a sample picture if that would help?* - yes, share that picture

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Apologies if I am not understanding, I made a picture sample of formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for an [*Excel spreadsheet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet) and not a [*csv*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) :

```
def fn(ser):
    return (
        ser.describe().to_frame().reset_index()
        .style.set_properties(**{"border": "1px solid"})
    )

from itertools import product
combs = product(df.groupby("service_model"), columns_for_stats)

N = 3 # maximum number of tables per bloc
SR, SC = 1, 2 # starts of row/col (Excel's index)
HS, VS = 1, 2 # number of separators (empty row/col)

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    for idx, ((sm, g), col) in enumerate(combs):
        sr, sc = (idx // N) * (8 + VS+1) + (SR-1), (idx % N) * (2 + HS) + (SC-1)
        fn(g[col]).to_excel(writer, startrow=sr, startcol=sc, index=False)
        fmt = writer.book.add_format({"align": "center", "bold": True, "border": 1})
        writer.sheets["Sheet1"].merge_range(sr, sc, sr, sc+1, f"{sm} - {col}", fmt)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Well done, that was godly